Find space in C
I am learning C and I am looking at some tutorials and I am now learning about while. In the video there was example of asking "what is your name?" and while is used there as a tool that when you try clicking enter it will say that you didn't enter a name and would ask you for name again. But I had idea what if someone uses space instead of just clicking enter. So I tried to find the answer to it on here and other sites but I couldn't find my exact problem and answer for it. I tried ctype.h library but it didnt work so I will show you code that worked but didn't work as I wanted.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    char name[25];
    
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    fgets(name, 25, stdin);
    name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

    while(strlen(name) == 0){
         printf("You didn't insert your name!!!\n");
         printf("What is your name?\n");
         fgets(name, 25, stdin);
         name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Your name is %s" name);

    return 0;

}


What do you mean by "code that worked but didn't work as I wanted"?

Since you're just getting started, this is a great program to learn how to use a debugger.  What have you figured out debugging your program?

Note: the posted code has a typo in printf("Your name is %s" name); Always copy/paste actual code.

So I don't know how to use debugger yet, and for the other comment, I meant it like It work as in the video, but I wanted it to also detect when someone types space because you could go around the strlen(name) == 0 just by typing space instead of clicking enter. Hope I clarified it more.

You need to do more rigorous testing on the input string.

Yea I didnt want to copy/paste my code because I dont have it in english, I am doing it just to learn so I type there in my native language so I didnt want to confuse you.

fgets() reads a line of input, it waits for newline. So none of the rest of the code runs until the user types Enter.

Yes, but do you understand that if there is one typo in your code, you may have introduced other mistakes too? Post actual code that compiles. If it isn't in English, change it to English, compile and test.

Side note: If you use a do...while loop instead of a while loop, you won't need to write the same 3 lines of code twice.

str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0'; is a nice hacker exploit if the first character entered in a null character.

As a beginner I wouldn't worry about learning all the quirks in the horrible stdio.h library. The most important thing to learn about that library is to avoid it in real production quality code. Learning to use a debugger as someone advised is a hundred times more useful knowledge (and also not unique to just the C language).

One solution would be to use the sscanf function from stdio.h to parse the string returned by fgets, to trim any leading spaces in the string, and store anything left in the name char array.
Like this:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char str[25];
    char name[25];
    
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    fgets(str, 25, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';

    while (strlen(str) == 0 || sscanf(str, " %24[^\n]", name) != 1){
         printf("You didn't insert your name!!!\n");
         printf("What is your name?\n");
         fgets(str, 25, stdin);
         str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Your name is %s\n", name);

    return 0;
}

This way if sscanf fails to store anything in name (meaning, in this case, that it doesn't return 1), then the user only typed spaces or pressed Enter.

Why use sscanf(str, " %24[^\n]", name) (looking for non-'\n' text) if str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; already lopped off any '\n'?

@chux-ReinstateMonica is it possible to use the %[^ specifier without indicating any character? But yes, in the case of using sscanf(str, " %24[^\n]", name) != 1 in the if statement, this code doesn't need to do str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; to replace the new line character, or check the length of the string, and they can be removed from the code.

For starters this statement
name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

in general is incorrect.  If the user will enter exactly 25 symbols then the symbol at the position strlen( name ) - 1 will not be the new line symbol '\n'.
Instead you need to write
name[ strcspn( name "\n" ) ] = '\0';

You can use similar function strspn to check that the entered string is empty (contains only space or tab characters) as for example
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

while( name[ strspn( name, " \t" ) ] == '\0' ){
     puts( "You didn't insert your name!!!" );
     puts( "What is your name?");
     fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
     name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
}

Or you can use function scanf instead of fgets like
scanf( " %24[^\n]", name );

In this case all leading white space characters will be skipped and the user will be unable to enter an empty string.
That is it is enough to use standard C functions that you should learn.
Another approach is to use function isalpha to try to find an alpha symbol in the array in a loop that requires writing more code.

Sorry, this code does not catch a single space entered.

@WeatherVane Entered single space is an  invalid input according to the question.

Yes, but this code accepts a single space and says Your name is  .

@WeatherVane How does this condition name[ strcspn( name, " \t" ) ] == '\0' accept one space?

Please compile and run your own program. Type a single space and then Enter.

@WeatherVane It was just a typo. I was not attentive.
